# Getting Precision And Scale In Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there a way in Entity Framework Core 3 to read the precision and scale specified on a column?

For example if I have:

```
[Column(TypeName = "numeric(5, 2)")]
```

Is there a way in code to access the precision value of 2 and scale value of 5?

I can access the "numeric(5, 2)" as a string but don't want to have it to parse that to get the 2 and 5.

The code I am using is this:

```
myModel.FindEntityType(myEntityType).FindProperty(myPropertyName).GetRelationalTypeMapping();
```

I can actually see whilst debugging, the scale and precision specified in the Parameters collection returned by the above code but as Parameters is protected there is no way to access it in code.

This was possible in Entity Framework (.Net Framework) using the `EdmProperty` class.

Thanks

Tristan.

Comment: Sorry, looks like they forgot to expose that info. You can post request here https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues